# Visual Studio 2012 can't include VB pages in C# website?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010, I could mix VB and C# pages and usercontrols in the same website.  Visual Studio 2012 doesn't seem to allow that.  I created a C# web project and when I add some old pages done in VB, it lists the .ascx and .ascx.vb files separately and won't compile.

I have a bunch of old stuff that was done in VB so please don't tell me I have to convert it all to C# before I can use VS2012.

Thanks!

It's ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably the fact that you've said yourself, you've created a "Web Project" vs "Web Site". Web Project is compiled by c# or vb compiler into a DLL and can't contain different languages. Web site is compiled by ASP.NET and each page compiled on its own.

I am sure that you're facing this "phenomenon"

Comment: Ah, right.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977220/is-it-possible-to-have-c-sharp-and-vb-net-in-the-same-asp-net-website