# Is Possible to run both C# and Vb Code in a single Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to have both c# and Vb (default.aspx.cs,index.aspx.vb ) in a single site. If so can you give me some ideas or Suggestions.

Comment: Hi everyone,is it possible without separating the Class libraries. and  as same i have a master page in VB, i want to merge the same into c#. Is that too possible. In that Example the Libraries has been separated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a "web site" then each page can use a specified language, because essentially each page is compiled separately. Some can use VB, some can use C#.

Otherwise "web application" which can use only one language.

Comment: You can even throw in a couple of PHP pages if you have it installed. And off course static HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked so many times on here.

See this blog for example - http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2007/02/28/14002.aspx

However, I personally recommend you don't mix languages in the same project. Just because you can doesn't mean you should and all that...

Comment: Can you link to a duplicate?

Comment: Yeh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977220/is-it-possible-to-have-c-sharp-and-vb-net-in-the-same-asp-net-website and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider seperating your business logic from your pages and making it ***loosely coupled***.

You can then build class libraries in `C#` and `VB.Net` in seperate projects which will represent your logic and reference the DLL's and call methods in your a single language from a `aspx.cs` or `aspx.vb`.

I wouldn't mix the two languages, especially in an area where it isn't needed.

I would even go as far as using a [code convertor](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to make your web page one language.