# Is it possible to add new C# pages to an existing VB.Net Web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an old VB.NET site and looking to add new pages to it. I'm not a VB man so is it possible to create new pages in the site but using C#?
I've never done this before and never seen it done so I'm guessing no.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can if you have a website project - have a look at this question (and answer): [Is it possible to have C# and vb.net in the same asp.net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977220/is-it-possible-to-have-c-sharp-and-vb-net-in-the-same-asp-net-website)

basically you do this in the config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation>
            <codeSubDirectories>
                <add directoryName="VB_Code"/>
                <add directoryName="CS_Code"/>
            </codeSubDirectories>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then create folders of the same name in the `App_Code` folder

More info on this here: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/03/30/ASPNET-20-Use-VBNET-and-C-within-the-App_Code-folder

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to notice that the question was relating to web sites.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278052/2999249

> No, you can't. An assembly/project (each project compiles to 1 assembly usually) has to be one language. However, you can use multiple assemblies, and each can be coded in a different language because they are all compiled to MSIL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix VB.NET and C# or other language in the same assembly (project).
But... you can have different projects (languages) in your solution.