# Gradually migrating ASP.NET website to use solely C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, migration

I'm responsible for maintaining a legacy ASP.NET website (not a web app) which contains a sizeable mix of VB and C#. I'm hoping to migrate the VB parts over to C# to have a bit more consistency.

Now I know you can use the `<codeSubDirectories>` tag in the `web.config` to indicate that certain code folders need to be rendered in a particular language; [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977220/is-it-possible-to-have-c-sharp-and-vb-net-in-the-same-asp-net-website) a decade ago. But, from what I can tell, that's only relevant to class libraries and API controllers.

I have this [Code Converter extension](https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter) installed on Visual Studio, which allows you to convert one file at a time, it seems to work brilliantly in terms of converting the file. My issue is that when debugging the new code to check it's definitely doing the right thing - it doesn't seem to hit the new code behind at all.

For a proof of concept, I'm using the `ascx` file for my nav menu - it doesn't do anything fancy, just shows and hides some parts based on whether or not the user is in certain roles.

My process has been:

1. Open the code behind (in this case: `TopMenu.ascx.vb`)
2. Right-click anywhere in the editor panel and select the `Convert To C#` option.
3. Sense check the newly generated `TopMenu.ascx.cs` file (it's in the
   right place, and seems like it should do the right thing)
4. Change the `TopMenu.ascx` file to look at `TopMenu.ascx.cs` rather
   than `TopMenu.ascx.vb`

So now the top line is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TopMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="Menus_TopMenu" %>
```

Which mimics the structure of other `ascx` files or `aspx` files that are looking at C# - however, when debugging the new file - it just doesn't hit the codebehind at all. Am I missing some obscure setting, or is this one of those "do it with a new file altogether" type processes?

Comment: Rebuild/redeploy the project?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried - short of deleting everything from the bin/debug folders

Comment: Instead of `CodeFile=` you could try `CodeBehind=` - one of the two should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my resolution was to rename the old file (i.e. change it to `TopMenu - VB.aspx`), then copy and paste it all to a new file using C#.